# What is the correct way to check if current process/thread is the main process/thread?

Tags: python

When spawning multiple threads I can do the following to check if the thread is the main thread:

```
isinstance(threading.currentThread(), threading._MainThread)
```

But this method relies on a "protected" member of the threading package and there is no similar type in multiprocessing library available for importing, so what is the correct way to check if the current process is the main process (and to do the same with thread?)

I am doing it like this for now:

```
multiprocessing.current_process().name == 'MainProcess'
```

but are those names reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one seems more reliable:

```
assert threading.current_thread() == threading.main_thread()
```

as it does not rely on static texts.

For processes, doing `process.name == 'MainProcess'` is not reliable. You should do this:

```
import re

def is_main_process(process_name):
    return not bool(re.match(r'Process-\d+', process_name))
```

The reason is that child processes are guaranteed to have a name in this format: `Process-N`.

Comment: great! but is there a way to do the same for processes?

Comment: found the confirmation of the multiprocessing part in the official docs here https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process (you can also provide the child process `name` in the constructor etc)